# Question about the Fundamental Group as a notion

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Can the fundamental group of some surface have more than one path homotopy class? Maybe this is a dumb question, but I'm really struggling with this

Comment: The easiest example is the torus. You have a path on top of it and one around it through the hole. That makes two classes a and b: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamentalgruppe#/media/Datei:Fundamental_group_torus2.png

Comment: Even easier: take the circle. You have a path that does nothing (the constant loop at $1$) and a path that goes around the circle once (or as many times more as you want). The fundamental group of the circle (i.e. $S^1$) is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You're asking whether all fundamental groups are trivial. Obviously, they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The fundmental group of a torus is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ so has infinitely many homotopy classes.